# Am I using utf8::is_utf8 correctly?

Tags: perl, utf-8, decode

Does this work correctly? Some error messages are already decode and some need do be decoded do get a correct output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw(:utf8 :std);
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);

# ...

if ( not eval{
    # some error-messages (utf8) are decoded some are not
    1 }
) {
    if ( utf8::is_utf8 $@ ) {
        print $@;
    }
    else {
        print decode_utf8( $@ );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the messages come out correct? If yes, it is probably working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I using utf8::is_utf8 correctly?

No. Any use of `utf8::is_utf8` is incorrect as you should never use it! Using `utf8::is_utf8` to guess at semantics of a string is what's known as an instance of [The Unicode Bug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#The-%22Unicode-Bug%22). Except for inspecting the internal state of variables when debugging Perl or XS module, `utf8::is_utf8` has no use.

It does not indicate whether the value in a variable is encoded using UTF-8 or not. In fact, that's impossible to know reliably. For example, does `"\xC3\xA9"` produce a string that's encoded using UTF-8 or not? Well, there's no way to know! It depends on whether I meant `"é"`, `"Ã©"` or something entirely different.

If the variable may contain both encoded and decoded strings, it's up to you to track that using a second variable. I strongly advise against this, though. Just decode everything as it comes in from the outside.

If you really can't, your best bet it to try to decode `$@` and ignore errors. It's [very unlikely](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=910190) that something readable that isn't UTF-8 would be valid UTF-8.

```
# $@ is sometimes encoded. If it's not,
# the following will leave it unchanged.
utf8::decode($@);

print $@;
```

Comment: I agree, except that `utf8::is_utf8` can be useful for working around The Unicode Bug on older Perls. Sadly we still have 5.8.8 machines in production...

Comment: @rjh, No, you just need `utf8::upgrade` or `utf8::downgrade`.

Comment: @Thorsten Schöning. Re "*So yes, the flag DOES distinguish exactly that.*", The passage you quoted doesn't contradict what I said at all. The docs are talking about how the string is stored internally, which is irrelevant here. My answer only talks about the *value of the variable*, not how it's stored internally.

Comment: @ikegami Your tests are simply wrong, just print the result of `is_utf8` directly after `inet_aton` and you will see the result is `0`, because you have a byte array. Passing that to `encode` is wrong, because that only works on character strings. Passing again to `decode` is wrong as well, because you don't have a UTF-8 encoded byte array, but something arbitrary different. `decode` only doesn't fail, but the problem is you making wrong assumptions, not the flag. Garbage in, garbage out. Your 2. example is dealing with a byte array as well, so `0` is expected output, regardless of Unicode.

Comment: @Thorsten Schöning, That's not how Perl works. Just like Perl considers zero to be zero whether stored as a IV, UV, NV, PV[UTF8=0] or PV[UTF8=1], Perl doesn't distinguish between string stored using PV[UTF8=0] or PV[UTF8=1]. is_utf8 says nothing about the string except how it's stored. You can verify this by using `print` or `eq` on the output of `inet_aton` before and after the encode-decode. `$_` still contains the exact same bytes. How the value is stored doesn't affect the value.

Comment: Using `utf8::is_utf8` to guess at semantics is what's known as an instance of [The Unicode Bug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#The-%22Unicode-Bug%22). When both `perl` (`print`, `eq`, `ord`, `length`, `sprintf "%vX"`, etc) and the Perl documentation disagrees with you, you should take a hint and stop spreading this misinformation!

Comment: Re "*Your 2. example is dealing with a byte array as well, so 0 is expected output, regardless of Unicode*", No, it's an array of Unicode Code Points. C9 is the Unicode Code Point for "É", not its UTF-8 encoding. The OP specifically asked if `is_utf8` is the correct way of checking if something is already decoded or not, which this clearly shows otherwise. Passing the string in my example to `decode` would be wrong because it's already decoded.

Comment: @ikegami Perl's docs are not disagreeing with me, they clearly distinguish between byte arrays and character strings and under which circumstances the UTF-8 flag is one or off and which input is expected. Just read the docs yourself: `encode`: "The UTF8 flag is turned off."; `downgrade`: "Can be used to make sure that the UTF-8 flag is off, e.g. when you want to make sure that the substr() or length() function works with the usually faster byte algorithm."

Comment: `length` couldn't be used to count the number of characters in a character string vs. the number of bytes(!) in the same string in arbitrary different encoding then, but that example is even mentioned in the docs for length: "Like all Perl character operations, length normally deals in logical characters, not physical bytes. For how many bytes a string encoded as UTF-8 would take up, use length(Encode::encode('UTF-8', EXPR))" Please explain that example without Perl distinguishing character strings and byte arrays. Of course a user would have needed to encode/decode correctly before.

Comment: Re "*Perl's docs are not disagreeing with me*", Again, they call what you are promoting the "The Unicode Bug", and the developers of Perl and of modules have been actively removing code suffering from this bug. /// Re "*they clearly distinguish between byte arrays and character strings*", Oh I know there are two storage formats. There's no doubt about that. What I said is that you can't imply meaning about the value of the string based on the storage format (i.e. based on the UTF8 flag).

Comment: Re "*downgrade: "Can be used to make sure that the UTF-8 flag is off, e.g. when you want to make sure that the substr() or length() function works with the usually faster byte algorithm."*", That actually support my point and contradicts yours. Like I said, changing the storage format doesn't change the string, and this is the reason you can upgrade and downgrade a variable as much as you want. You can't imply meaning about the value of the string based on the storage format (i.e. based on the UTF8 flag).