# Perl UTF8 to UTF16 conversion error - wide characters

Tags: perl, unicode

Can someone tell me why this snippet fails with the following error? I have also tried 
 `utf8::downgrade()` before calling `from_to()` with no success. Using Perl 5.14.2.

Any ideas??

Code:

```
use Encode qw(from_to);
use HTML::Entities;

$s = "&#3617;&#3627;&#3633;&#3624";
$foo = decode_entities($s);
print "is foo UTF8? ", utf8::is_utf8($foo), "\n";
from_to($foo, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
```

Output:

```
is foo UTF8? 1
Cannot decode string with wide characters at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/Encode.pm line 194.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `utf8::is_utf8` does not do what you think it does. It provides details about internal storage of the string, [nothing you should ever need to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579560/am-i-using-utf8is-utf8-correctly/14584079#14584079).

The problem is that your string is not encoded using UTF-8. It's not encoded at all. `decode_entities` both takes and returns a decoded string, a string of Unicode code points.

You could use

```
encode('UTF-16', decode_entities(decode('UTF-8', $foo)))
```